# System of two congruence equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

How can I solve this system?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
9x \equiv 5 \pmod{10} \\ 
14x \equiv 8 \pmod{18} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simplify this system to a system of congruences in the form $x\equiv a_i \pmod{m_i}$, where the moduli $m_i$ are coprime.

Namely, since $9$ is a unit mod. $1$, with inverse $9$, the first congruence is equivalent to
$$ x\equiv 9\cdot 5\equiv 5\pmod{10}. $$

The second congruence is equivalent to 
$$7x\equiv 4\pmod 9,$$
and as the inverse of $7$ mod. $9$ is $4$, it is in turn equivalent to
$$x\equiv 4\cdot 4\equiv 7\pmod 9.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: $9 ⋅ 5 = 5$ ? That makes no sense

Comment: $\color{red}{\equiv}~ 5$. It makes perfectly sense. You forget $5$ is a zero divisor modulo $10$.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: For instance $2\cdot 5\equiv 0$.

Comment: @Bernard I still don't understand. Why $2⋅5≡0$?

Comment: @Bernard What does $≡$ mean?

Comment: @Jonsa: it means `congruent to`. Indeed $2\cdot 5=10$ and $10$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $10$.

Comment: Why $10$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $10$ and what does "modulo" mean?

Comment: This means $10$ and $0$  have the same remainder when divided by $10$. So the congruence class of $10$ is made up of all mutiples of $10$, the congruence class of $1$ is made up of $\{1,11,21,...,-9,-19,...\}$. Is that clear?

Comment: How did you transfer that $9$ from $9x$ to $9⋅5$?

Comment: Why $x≡4⋅4≡7(mod9)$ and not $x≡4⋅7≡4(mod9)$?

Comment: For you first question:  starting from $9x\equiv 5$, I multiplied both sides of the congruence by the modular inverse of $9$, which happens to be $9$ itself.  So it becomes $9(9x)=9^2x\equiv 9\cdot5$, i.e. $1\cdot x\equiv 9\cdot5$. Similarly for your 2nd question: both ides are multiplied by the inverse of $4$ modulo $10$., which is $4$ (I admit the fact these numbers are their own modular inverses can be confusing for the novice).

Comment: How can I find the modular inverse of a number?

Comment: For small number and modulus, you can do that by trial and error, considering  successive multiples of the number, until one of them is $1$ more than a multiple of the modulus. Other than that, a standard algorithm  consists in performing the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to obtain a *Bézout's relation* between the number and the modulus: the modular inverse is the coefficient of the number in the relation.

Comment: Fascinating comment thread, I must say. An almost perfect example of the reason why answering questions with zero context is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

writing your equations in the form
$$9x=5+10m$$
$$14x=8+18n$$ then you will get by eliminating $x$
$$7m-81n=1$$
solving this Diophantine equation we obtain
$$m=58+81C,n=57+7C$$ where $C$ is a constant
from the first equation we get
$$x=\frac{5}{9}+\frac{10}{9}m$$ and from here we obtain
$$14\left(\frac{5}{9}+\frac{10}{9}m\right)=8+18n$$ etc

Answer (score 0):

We have $$9x\equiv5\equiv45\pmod{10}\implies x\equiv5\pmod{10}$$ and $$14x\equiv8\pmod{18}\implies7x\equiv4\equiv49 \pmod9\implies x\equiv7\pmod9$$ by the Cancellation Rule.

Now for the first congruence, $$x=5, 15, 25, ...$$ and since $25\equiv7\pmod9$, the solution is $$\boxed{x\equiv25\pmod{90}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$9x\equiv_{10}5$, multiply both sides by $9$ to get
$81x\equiv_{10}x\equiv_{10}45\equiv_{10}5$, so $x\equiv_{10}5$

$14x\equiv_{18}8$, this is the same as solving $7x\equiv_9 4$, mutiply by $4$ on both sides to get $28x\equiv_{9}x\equiv_9 16\equiv_9 7$, so $x\equiv_9 7$.

This yields $x\equiv_{90}25$

Answer (score 0):

The plan: Solve each [linear congruence equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html) individually, then combine the results using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Solve the first linear congruence equation using the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $9$:

$9x\equiv 5 \bmod 10 \\
\text{Since }9\cdot 9= 81\equiv 1 \bmod 10, \quad 9^{-1}\equiv 9 \bmod 10 \\
9\cdot 9x\equiv 9\cdot5 \bmod 10 \\
x\equiv 9\cdot5\equiv 45\equiv 5 \bmod 10 \\
$

The second linear congruence equation needs a factor of two taken out from coefficients and modulus before it can be solved similarly:

$14x\equiv 8 \bmod 18 \\
\Rightarrow 7x \equiv 4\bmod 9$

The reason is clear if the relationship is expressed as $14x=8+18k$, since then it is clear that $7x=4+9k$ is also true.

Now we have $\gcd(7,9)=1$ we will be able to find a modular inverse:

$9x\equiv 5 \bmod 10 \\
\text{Since }7\cdot 4= 28\equiv 1 \bmod 9, \quad 7^{-1}\equiv 4 \bmod 9 \\
4\cdot 7x\equiv 4\cdot4 \bmod 9 \\
x\equiv 4\cdot4\equiv 16\equiv 7 \bmod 9 \\
$

So we have
$\begin{cases}
x\equiv 5 \bmod 10 \\
x\equiv 7 \bmod 9 \\
\end{cases}$

Since $\gcd(10,9)=1$, the Chinese remainder theorem tells us there will be a solution to this system modulo $10\cdot 9=90$.

A simple search of values qualifying as $5\bmod 10$: $5,15,25,\ldots$ gives us $x\equiv 25\bmod 90$.